# How to set RecyclerView Max Height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to set Max Height of RecylerView.I am able to set max height using below code.Below code makes height 60% of current screen.

```
     DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int a = (displaymetrics.heightPixels * 60) / 100;
    recyclerview1.getLayoutParams().height = a;
```

But now problem is that, if it have no item then also its height is 60%.
So I want to set its height 0 when no item in it.

I want to achieve something like this.

```
    if(recyclerview's height > maxHeight)
then set recyclerview's height to maxHeight
    else dont change the height of recyclerview.
```

How can i set it?
Please help me, I am stuck with it

Comment: RecyclerView apparently comes with a parameter called maxHeight in XML, _but it does not work_.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here is something, you need. Subclass the RecyclerView and override onMeasure as following:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Utils.dpsToPixels(240), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
}
```

Make sure, you give proper number of pixels as the first argument in `makeMeasureSpec()`. I personally needed RecyclerView, that is 240dps at most.

Comment: How did u subclass the RecyclerView, please?

Comment: @Dusan created a new class, that extended RecyclerView.

Comment: This solution works when you add elements in Array but doesn't work when you remove the elements from the array. That means we can not decrease the height of the RecyclerView once we increased the height.

Comment: This is literally the only way to have a recycler view with a max height. Bad Google.

Answer (score 58):

ConstraintLayout offers maximum height for its children.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like the best solution. Sadly, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure to update the constraint layout dependency or else there is a bug in older versions where the  recycler view is hidden when the recycler view becomes scrollable

Comment: This solution is perfect! and fixed my ADA as well. thank-you so much.

app:layout_constraintHeight_max="300dp"  -> very valuable!

Comment: Solved my case app:layout_constraintHeight_max="300dp" for recycler view

Answer (score 34):

I think this will work at least it worked for me

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/Id_const_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               >
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/Id_my_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_space"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/Id_const_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Id_const_layout"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_max="150dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Id_const_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Id_const_layout"
            >
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can change the `constraintHeight_max` and `constraintHeight_min` according to your needs.

Answer (score 26):

We can optimize @Fattum 's method a little bit.
We can use `app:maxHeight` to set the `maxHeight`. One can use `dp` or `px` as you like.

```
public class MaxHeightRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private int mMaxHeight;

    public MaxHeightRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MaxHeightRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context, attrs);
    }

    public MaxHeightRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize(context, attrs);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray arr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MaxHeightScrollView);
        mMaxHeight = arr.getLayoutDimension(R.styleable.MaxHeightScrollView_maxHeight, mMaxHeight);
        arr.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (mMaxHeight > 0) {
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mMaxHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

values/attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="MaxHeightScrollView">
    <attr name="maxHeight" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: This solution works when you add elements in Array but doesn't work when you remove the elements from the array. That means we can not decrease the height of the RecyclerView once we increased the height.

Answer (score 19):

After trying way too many complicated suggestions, I finally figured this out through trial and error.

First, wrap the RecyclerView in some sort of layout. In my case, I used a constraint layout, and I even had other elements in that layout above and below the RecyclerView. Set the height of the layout to auto adjust by setting it to 0dp, then set the default layout height constraint as wrap and define a layout max height constraint.

Then, on your RecyclerView, set the height to wrap_content and layout_constrainedHeight to true.

Here is what it should look like:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="600px"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_max="450px">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_ToTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I also think this is the best answer, although you have a typo: `app:layout_constraintTop_ToTopOf` should be `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf`

Comment: Does giving an explicit max hight work on different devices that have different dimensions?

Comment: Also, instead of `px` we need to use `dp`.

Answer (score 3):

ill add my 2 cents i needed a recycler view with a max height and min height and wrap content between the 2

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/group_card_recycler_view_holder"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_max="@dimen/group_recycler_view_height"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="@dimen/card_sentence_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/group_name_container"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/myButtonLayout">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
                android:id="@+id/group_card_recycler_view"/>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

write this statements inside if else
 and let me know ,

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=recyclerview.getLayoutParams();
params.height=100;
recyclerview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: > set its height 0 when no item in it.how could you determine this ?@Maulik009 , at that place . yes @Piyush ,bhai :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WRAP_CONTENT in your RecyclerView. It will auto measure your recyclerview according to its content.

You can also calculate current height and set max height. So Recyclerview will use wrap_content attribute value until max height.

```
public static void getTotalHeightofRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

        RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();

        int totalHeight = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
            View mView = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView

            mView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

            totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        if (totalHeight > 100) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = recyclerView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 100;
            recyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have kept wrap_content in layout. But i want to set its Max Height so that it will scroll in current screen only. Because I have buttons below it that i want to show always.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference

err on line

  View mView = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView

Comment: can you share code? Looks like you are calling notifyDataSetChange() just before findViewHolderForAdapterPosition.

Comment: No i am not calling notifyDataSetChange.

Comment: recyclerview1.setAdapter(sectionAdapter1);
recyclerview1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = recyclerview1.getAdapter();
getTotalHeightofRecyclerView(recyclerview1);

Answer (score 1):

If you have a RecyclerView designed to hold items of equal physical size and you want a no-brainer way to limit its height without extending RecyclerView, try this:

```
int maxRecyclerViewHeightPixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
    MAX_RECYCLERVIEW_HEIGHT_DP,
    getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
);

MyRecyclerViewAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), myElementList);
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myRecyclerView.getLayoutParams();

if (myElementList.size() <= MAX_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS_TO_DISPLAY_AT_ONE_TIME) {
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //LinearLayout must be replaced by whatever layout type encloses your RecyclerView
}
else {
    params.height = maxRecyclerViewHeightPixels;
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

This works both for Linear and Grid RecyclerViews, you just need to play with the numbers a bit to suit your taste. Don't forget to set the height to WRAP_CONTENT after you populate the RecyclerView.

You may also have to set the height again every time the size of myElementList changes, but that's not a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use ConstraintLayout and setting height constraint on Recycleview.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/CL_OUTER_RV_Choose_Categories "
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RV_Choose_Categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please note that before Lollipop, the recycleview will not scroll. As a solution, add the below code in the activity's oncreate.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        ConstraintLayout CL_OUTER_RV_Choose_Categories = findViewById(R.id.CL_OUTER_RV_Choose_Categories);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) CL_OUTER_RV_Choose_Categories.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    }
```

This will ensure that height is fixed only on supported devices, and the complete recycle view is shown on older devices.

Do let me know if there is any better way.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem, and wanted to share a new, up-to-date answer. This one works on at least Android 9 and Android Studio v. 4.0.

Wrap the RecyclerView in a ConstraintLayout, as some of the answers here have suggested. But it does not appear you can set the maximum height of that layout in XML. Instead, you must set it in code, as follows: Give the ConstraintLayout an ID, and then, in your onCreate or onViewCreated method for the activity or fragment, respectively, in question - for example, to set a max height of 200 dp:

```
findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.[YOUR ID]).maxHeight = 200 // activity
view.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.[YOUR ID]).maxHeight = 200 // fragment
```

Annoyingly, ConstraintLayout *does* expose an XML attribute `android:minHeight` but *no* `android:maxHeight`.

Even more annoyingly, RecyclerView itself apparently comes with *an XML attribute* named `android:maxHeight`, but that attribute *does not work*.

Answer (score -6):

You can just set a specific height to any value in the xml code and set the visibility to **gone**. Then you set the visibility to **Visible** in Java, when you want to inflate it. Here is an example;

.xml

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

.java

```
recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```