# How to add recyclerview with Edittext and a button which is bottom aligned?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-recyclerview

This codes works fine when the items in the recycler view are 3 or 4. When the items in recycler view are more then 4 then the edit text field goes out of the screen.Like in image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb4ut.jpg

EditText should not go below Bottom aligned button when there will be multiple items in recyclerview. How can I achieve this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IkA6.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorWhitex"
tools:context=".Fragments.RecordOdometerFragments.RecordOdometer">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/car_selection_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/odometer_view"
            android:layout_below="@+id/car_selection_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_red_corners">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/odometer_edittext"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:paddingEnd="64dp"
                android:maxLines="9"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:hint="Input meter reading"
                android:background="@null"
                android:paddingStart="16dp" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_none_black_24dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_black_24dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_corner_radius"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Done"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Firstly, this Xml layout should have a closing tag `</LinearLayout> ` you have given `</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: The RelativeLayout holds the RecyclerView and the RelativeLayout that holds the  EditText but only is not relatively positioned to anything. My guess is as the recyclerview is filled with content, the height increases and there is no constraint to prevent it from extending to the bottom of the view.

Comment: @AkhilaMadari, the closing tag he has actually does match up, he's just missing another closing tag for the linearlayout in the code shown.

Comment: @charliebeckwith Agree, kindly tell me how to set that constraint to prevent it from extending to the bottom of the view.

Comment: use layout weight to split the screen

Comment: I have also tried layout weight property to solve this issue but fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is to use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) and to prevent your RecyclerView from pushing out your `odometer_view`, explore something like [How to set RecyclerView Max Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694355/how-to-set-recyclerview-max-height)

But taking note of your updated requirement, you can still hack it with some creative *padding* here. Since it seems like you know the height of your `odometer_view`, based on its contents, @ `35dp`+2x`16dp`, you can give your RecyclerView the same bottom padding, and then just align their bottoms together.

(I've stripped out the extra code)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/button" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/car_selection_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="67dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/odometer_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/car_selection_rv" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/odometer_edittext"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So really just two items:

1. `android:paddingBottom="67dp"`
2. `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/car_selection_rv"`

Now your `odometer_view` will essentially float above the bottom padding of your recyclerview, wherever it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I want the recycler View attached with edit text in the case of 1 or 2 items in recycler View. But in this case you have aligned 
edit text to alignParentBottom.

Comment: I want the edit text to be stick with recycler View. When the size of recycler view increases, edit text shouldn't extend to the bottom of the view(button)

Comment: Then like JonMan08 mentioned, you'll have to look into ConstraintLayout to control the height growth of your recyclerview so it does not push out your odometer_view, explore something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694355/how-to-set-recyclerview-max-height

Comment: I've also updated my answer with a different way to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your working answer. Highly appreciated. Have a happy and blessed life Elahi Ameen.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend that you use the [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/). You are able to create complex layouts relatively easily without having to nest multiple layouts.

Comment: I have also tried this with constraint layout but fails