# why recycler view max height doesn't work? Also i tried recycler view add inside constraint layout but it doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to **max height to recycler view** but doesn't work for me. I found some answers but they didn't work for me.
I tried many ways to fix that. but I couldn't found the answer. this is XML code. Anyone can help me to solve that problem

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewItems"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_max="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set RecyclerView Max Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694355/how-to-set-recyclerview-max-height)

Comment: @user1506104 
i know this question already asked in here. But theirs solutions didn't work for me. Thats why again posted this question.
Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code on your xml activity file. Hope this will work.

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewItems"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_max="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear to me but if you want the recyclerView to take all of the screen space you should use this :

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewItems"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you want to limit your recyclerview height I would not recommend using fixed sized in dp - use guideline/barrier to make your recyclerView take only some percent of the screen, for example if you want your view only take 30% of your screen use guidelines with 30% different  and constrain your view to them like this:

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewItems"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: i want to add recycler view inside dialog. i used recycler view height as wrap content . when lot of items have dialog height so big. when recycler view height goes more than 400dp (as a example) it should be stopped (i mean height) . then other item to view scroll down.
But i used max width in recycler view it didn't work. Also i created a constraint layout and add recycler view inside it and set height to 0dp .  it didn't worked

Comment: This is not a good practice(the fixed sizes), what is wrong with my answer? why not use constraint layout with guidelines like the example I gave?

Comment: didn't work bro. ( I used recycler view in dialog) it could be the reason this method didn't work....

Comment: Ok in that case creat custom dialog with custom layout and in your layout try to do as i sujested in my answer with guidlines.This should work